# Invertible matrices question

Tags: matrices

I have been playing around with this exercise, I know the answer is in front of me, but the Matrix is foggy and I can't seem to find my way out of the loophole I am currently in.

I am given this matrix, named *E*

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        c-1 & 18 & 2 \\
        0 & c & -5 \\
        0 & 0 & c+3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I am asked to find all values of c for which the matrix is invertible.

This part I have figured out.

What troubles me is the second question, which asks me to find all values of c for which the matrix $$ ({E^TE)^{1821}} $$ is invertible.

I kinda know it's probably the same thing, but I haven't been able to justify this. Or I could be wrong.Whatever the case, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't said what $E$ is.  Can you please edit that into the question?

Comment: Sorry for the omission. E is the name of the matrix provided

Comment: $\det(E^TE)=\det(E)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. The matrix $(E^TE)^k$ ($k$ any positive integer) is invertible if and only if $E^TE$ is invertible: if $E^TE$ is not invertible, then its rank is less than $3$ and so…
2. $E^TE$ has the same rank as $E$.